# Converting code to ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have just started learning es6 module system. I have some es5 javascript code which I want to transform to es6 modules. There are 3 javascript files

**workflow-designer.js**

```
var WorkflowDesigner = (function () {
  var constructor = function (element, options) {
    var component = this;
    if ($(element).hasClass('panel')) {
      component.panel = $(element);
    } else {
      component.panel = $(element).closest('.panel');
    }
  };

  extend(Object, constructor, {
    getWorkflowName: function () {
      return 'WorkflowName001';
    },

    nextStep: function () {
      var o = {};
      o['id'] = -1;
      //some code here
      return o;
    },

    prevStep: function () {
      var o = {};
      o['id'] = -1;
      //some code here
      return o;
    }
  });

  return constructor;

})();

(function ($) {    
    $.fn.createWorkflowDesigner = function (options) {
        debugger;
        return this.map(function (index, element) {
            return new WorkflowDesigner($(element), options);
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
```

**extend.js**

```
function extend(parent, child, methods) {
    debugger;
    let Surrogate = function () {};
    Surrogate.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new Surrogate();
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
    // Add a reference to the parent's constructor
    child.parentConstructor = parent;

    // Copy the methods passed in to the prototype
    for (let name in methods) {
        if (methods.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            child.prototype[name] = methods[name];
        }
    }
    // so we can define the constructor inline
    return child;
}
```

There a third file **utils.js** which contain extension methods like

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
    Array.prototype.find = function (predicate) {
        //some code here

    }
}

if (!Array.prototype.doSomething) {
    Array.prototype.doSomething = function (predicate) {
        //some code here

    }
}

$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    //somthing here.        
});
```

I know that to convert the code to es6 modules, I can simply export the `extend` function like `export function extend(.....)` in the **extend.js** file. However, I am not 100% sure how to convert the **workflow-designer** and **utils.js** to es6 modules.

I suspect that I need to something like below to convert my workflow-designer.js to es6 module:

```
export default function workflowDesigner() {
    let constructor = function (element, options) {
        options = options || {};
        let component = this;
        if ($(element).hasClass('panel')) {
            component.panel = $(element);
        } else {
            component.panel = $(element).closest('.panel');
        }
    };
    //rest of the code here....

    return constructor;

};
```

Please let me know if I am moving into the right direction or not.

**UPDATE:**
As per @Bergi's suggesion I changed the `extend` function like below:

```
export default function extend(parent, child, methods) {

  child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
  child.prototype.constructor = child;

  // Add a reference to the parent's constructor
  child.parentConstructor = parent;

  // Copy the methods passed in to the prototype
  Object.assign(child, methods);

  // so we can define the constructor inline
  return child;
}
```

However, now I am getting error message that *"workflowDesigner.getWorkflowName is not a function"*

In the debug mode I can see that this function is available at `workflowDesigner.__proto__.constructor.getWorkflowName`. With the old code it works fine.

Comment: I think you definitely should not have `$(document).keyup(…)` in a file called util.js.

Comment: When moving to ES6, you'll also want to use `class` syntax. Also you should never need to `extend(Object, …)` - it's the default. Just `Object.assign()` the `methods` onto your prototype. Oh, and use ES5 `Object.create` instead of that `Surrogate` constructor thing.

Comment: So what you are saying about the function in extend.js is that I need to replace the `Surrogate` thing with `child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);` and `child.prototype.constructor = child;` and then finally copy the methods with `Object.assign(child, methods);`. Am I right?

Comment: You also mentioned that I don't need to `extend(Object, .....)` as it's the default. Now in my application this `extend` function inside **extend.js** file is always invoked like `extend(Object, constructor, {......})`. So by the look of it, I don't need `Surrogate` or `child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);` at all. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop the IIFE from your module pattern - ES6 modules come with their own scope.

```
import extend from './extend.js';

export default function WorkflowDesigner(element, options) {
  if ($(element).hasClass('panel')) {
    this.panel = $(element);
  } else {
    this.panel = $(element).closest('.panel');
  }
}

extend(Object, WorkflowDesigner, {
  getWorkflowName: () => 'WorkflowName001',
  …
});

const $ = jQuery; // you might want to solve this with a proper `import`
$.fn.createWorkflowDesigner = function (options) {
  debugger;
  return this.map(function (index, element) {
    return new WorkflowDesigner($(element), options);
  });
};
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it works like a charm. However, the extend function doesn't work properly if I use Object.assign to assign methods to the prototype. Please see the updated question

Comment: You still want to assign them to `child.prototype`, not to `child`